# Is there a good book for combinatorics for programmers?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

The book should be easy to read, or at least average. The level for reading such a book is the MATH and CS school curriculum. It should also be expanded on topics related to CS, and also be narrated in a light manner. It should be kind of in a intro tutorial before starting a middle combinatorics.

P.S need such combinatorics after which I can understand the course of data structures and algorithms. Also understand the course of computing algorithms.

Comment: I will point out that you never did state your question.  It *appears* as though you are looking for a book recommendation.  This should have been made much clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combinatorics is important if you wish to be a competitive programmer.Go through concepts from the given pdf and try to practice as much as you can from platforms like codeforces and codechef.[Combinatorics PDF](http://www.math.utk.edu/~wagner/papers/comb.pdf)